# How to return count value in ADO.NET in C# function?

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have created ADO.NET in C# where I want to return count value. My procedure `GetAllEmployees @UserId` which returns total count of employee. But `list` always returns `1` eventhough the `CountId` shows `0`. I am doing something silly. Can anyone please help me.

```
  public List<MyEmployee> GetAll(int UserId)
    {
        clsClass cls = new clsClass();
        DataSet ds;
        List<MyEmployee> list = new List<MyEmployee>();

        SqlParameter[] prms = new SqlParameter[1];
        string sSQL;
        sSQL = "exec GetAllEmployees @UserId";
        prms[0] = new SqlParameter("@UserId", SqlDbType.Int);
        prms[0].Value = UserId;
        ds = cls.CommandwithParams(sSQL, prms);
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            list.Add(
                new MyEmployee
                {
                    CountId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CountId"])

                });
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, Sorry I will change to ADO.NET.

Comment: @TheGeneral, Sorry that was my mistake. I changed to `ADO.NET`

Comment: Can you share the code for the `GetAllEmployees` procedure? So we can understand what's going on

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, `ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAllEmployees]  

 @UserId int
 
AS
BEGIN
 -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
 -- interfering with SELECT statements.
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
 Select count(CountId) as CountId from Employees
 
   UserID=@UserId
END`

Comment: So, the problem is that you end up with `list` having a single item with `CountId = 0`?

Comment: @Mohammad, it returns number of `countid`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, Yes, it always gives me `0` and `list` always returns `1`. But `dt.Rows` rows total number of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest declaring a variable like blow then add to it list.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
 {
          var emp=new MyEmployee
            {
                CountId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CountId"])
            });  
          list.Add(emp);
 }
```

Comment: It throws error `cannot convert from int to xx.xx.Models.MyEmployee`

Comment: I have already written that class and `CountId` is declared as `int`